# Context Switch in operating system

Tags: operating-system

What are the action taken by the kernel during context switching

Comment: This sounds like homework.  Maybe you could look it up in your textbook?

Comment: hey i knew the answer but i am looking for some standard view from experts on it.and this isn't a homework.

Comment: If you knew the answer, then it might be wise to state what you already knew and specified that you were looking for other opinions, otherwise it just seems as if you are trying to get someone to do your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PCB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_control_block) is stored  in kernel memory.

> Implementations differ, but in general a PCB will include, directly or
>   indirectly:
>
> 1. The identifier of the process (a process identifier, or PID)
> 2. Register values for the process including, notably, the program
>      counter and stack pointer values for the process.
> 3. The address space for the process    Priority (in which higher
>      priority process gets first preference. eg., nice value on Unix
>      operating systems)
> 4. Process accounting information, such as when the process was last
>      run, how much CPU time it has accumulated, etc.
> 5. Pointer to the next PCB i.e. pointer to the PCB of the next process
>      to run    I/O Information (i.e. I/O devices allocated to this
>      process, list of opened files, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I think first it will depend on whether it is process or thread context switch.

Generally speaking, some registers and system-related data will be saved. And another set of the data will be restored in order for the next task, process or thread to continue running.

Basically, kernel saves old environment and sets up new environment for the job.